# I'm not able to convert the array of objects to format that can be send and store to web server

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, http-post

I'm trying to send array of objects to the web server using urlsession. I need to convert the array of objects into some format than can be send and store into the server.

model.swift

```
class UserDetails 
{
    var name: String
    var phNumber: Int
    var pincode : Int
    var numberOfItems: Int

    init(name: String, number: Int, pin : Int, items: Int) {

        self.name = name
        self.phNumber = number
        self.pincode = pin
        self.numberOfItems = items
    }

}


/* viewController.swift */

    var users: [UserDetails] = []
    func sendLabDetails(userId: Int,users: [UserDetails], completion: @escaping (_ serverResponse: NSDictionary) -> Void)
        {
            let parameters = ["user_id": userId, "users": users] as [String : Any]
    }
```

I think I'm doing wrong in calling the API with objects. Please help me with some code on how to convert the array of objects into array of dictionaries or any other JSON supported format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Dictionary` you can convert it to JSON using `JSONEncoder`:

```
 let parameters = ["user_id": "newID", "users": "newUser"]
 do{
    let jsonParameter = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
}catch{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

> ***NOTE:*** To encode an object means that this object conforms to protocol `Codable`. `Any` does not conform to this protocol, so it cannot be encoded as JSON.
>   In order to do this, you can make your class `UserDetails` to conform that protocol or you have to change your data structure, because `[String:Any]` is not good.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
class UserDetails: Codable //Be sure to make the class to conform to this protocol if needed
{
    var name: String
    var phNumber: Int
    var pincode : Int
    var numberOfItems: Int

    init(name: String, number: Int, pin : Int, items: Int) {

        self.name = name
        self.phNumber = number
        self.pincode = pin
        self.numberOfItems = items
    }

}

//Now you can encode:

var users: [UserDetails] = []

    func sendLabDetails(userId: Int,users: [UserDetails], completion: @escaping (_ serverResponse: NSDictionary) -> Void)
        {
            let parameters = ["user_id": userId, "users": users]
            do{
    let jsonParameter = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
    //HERE YOU CAN USE jsonParameter to send data to server
}catch{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
    }
```

Comment: getting error as "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" in .encode(parameters)

Comment: As I said in the answer, you get this error because of Any. Any cannot be converted because does not conform to Codable